# PHP remove and delete something after one special character

Tags: php

I have a very simple PHP question about replacing in string.

For example, our string is this :

```
This is a test - spam text
```

and i need to convert this string to this :

```
This is a test
```

I mean i want to detect the place of `-` charachter and delete everything after that.

How to do it ?

Comment: using `explode()` ->`$str = 'This is a test - spam text'; $str = explode('-',$str); echo $str[0];`?

Comment: You can use $splitedArr = preg_split("/[-]+/", $text); and you can get your result with $splitedArr[0].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

```
$result = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-'));
```

Answer (score 2):

use [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to return part of a string and [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

```
$str = 'This is a test - spam text';

$newStr = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-'));
//               start ^  end ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$str = "This is a test - spam text";
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos( $str, '-'));
```

`strpos()` detects where - is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular expressions to match anything after the - character.

This should work

```
/-.*/
```

When you match the string then you can replace the content using simple string functions.